# Pandas: Get number of occurrences of an attribute when target variable has a certain value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset, df, that looks as so:

```
    Age     Income  Student     Credit Rating     Loan
0   <=30    high    no          fair              no
1   <=30    high    no          excellent         no
2   31-40   high    no          fair              yes
3   >40     medium  no          fair              yes
4   >40     low     yes         excellent         no
5   31-40   low     yes         excellent         yes
```

I have created a list containing all the attributes:

```
attributes = ["Age", "Income", "Student", "Credit Rating"]
```

and a dictionary for the attribute values:

```
attribute_values = {
    "Age": ["<=30", "31-40", ">40"],
    "Income": ["low", "medium", "high"],
    "Student": ["yes", "no"],
    "Credit Rating": ["fair", "excellent"]
}
```

I am trying to not just get the value counts of the attributes, but also the number of counts the attribute correlates to a 'yes' or 'no' in the Loan column, or my target variable.

I have:

```
for attribute in attributes:
    v_count = df[attribute].value_counts()
    print("attribute", attribute)
    for att_value in attribute_values[attribute]:
        print(att_value, v_count[att_value])
```

This would give me an output as so:

```
attribute Age
<=30 2
31-40 2
>40 2
attribute Income
low 2
medium 1
high 3
attribute Student
yes 4
no 2
attribute Credit Rating
fair 3
excellent 3
```

However, what I am also wanting for each attribute value is how many of these attribute value counts are yes or no (based on target value). For example, Age <=30 has a value count of 2, of these 2, both are 'no'. For Credit Rating of fair, of these 3,1 is 'no' and 2 are 'yes'. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this:

```
for attribute in df.drop(columns="Loan").columns:
    print("Attribute:", attribute)
    print(df.groupby([attribute, 'Loan']).size())
```

You can get:

```
Attribute: Age
Age    Loan
31-40  yes     2
<=30   no      2
>40    no      1
       yes     1
dtype: int64
Attribute: Income
Income  Loan
high    no      2
        yes     1
low     no      1
        yes     1
medium  yes     1
dtype: int64
Attribute: Student
Student  Loan
no       no      2
         yes     2
yes      no      1
         yes     1
dtype: int64
Attribute: Credit Rating
Credit Rating  Loan
excellent      no      2
               yes     1
fair           no      1
               yes     2
dtype: int64
```

And plus you don't need the list and dict you've created, you get a cleaner code.

Other option: converting to DataFrame and rename column for a prettier look

```
for attribute in df.drop(columns="Loan").columns:
    print("Attribute:", attribute)
    print(pd.DataFrame(df.groupby([attribute, 'Loan']).size()).rename(columns={0:"Count"}))
```

Output:

```
Attribute: Age
            Count
Age   Loan       
31-40 yes       2
<=30  no        2
>40   no        1
      yes       1
Attribute: Income
             Count
Income Loan       
high   no        2
       yes       1
low    no        1
       yes       1
medium yes       1
Attribute: Student
              Count
Student Loan       
no      no        2
        yes       2
yes     no        1
        yes       1
Attribute: Credit Rating
                    Count
Credit Rating Loan       
excellent     no        2
              yes       1
fair          no        1
              yes       2
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html#pandas.DataFrame.melt) before `value_counts`:

```
df.melt('Loan', var_name='attribute').value_counts()
```

Output:

```
Loan  attribute      value    
no    Age            <=30         2
      Student        no           2
yes   Student        no           2
      Credit Rating  fair         2
      Age            31-40        2
no    Income         high         2
      Credit Rating  excellent    2
      Income         low          1
      Student        yes          1
      Age            >40          1
yes   Age            >40          1
      Credit Rating  excellent    1
no    Credit Rating  fair         1
yes   Income         high         1
                     low          1
                     medium       1
      Student        yes          1
dtype: int64
```